# Sufficient condition for inverse function to be differentible

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I know that if the function is one-one, onto and continuous on compact set then its inverse function is continuous.I  am interested is there any such condition for differentiability of an inverse function. Sorry In advanced if my question was wrong. As this thought just come to my mind I searched but I did not get anything .
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: every calculus textbook should have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You need $f$ to be differentiable at $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f’(f^{-1}(x))\ne{}0$ for every $x$.

Comment: You can think intuitively about the $\ne{}0$ condition because the tangents of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are perpendicular and thus their slopes multiply to 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got Now